# Predressed key detection using Python

Tags: python, keyboard, key, keyevent, detect

Can the ability to detect keys that have been pressed due to software, hardware, drivers, etc. be used as specific modules or implemented with Python?

ex)

```py
import @@@
@@@.pressed_key()

>>> ["A", "2"]
```

I am looking for a function that detects a key that has already been pressed. The search contains almost real-time detection